# RecordSet = Nothing after SQL query returns value

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, dao

I'm trying to assign the result of an SQL query to a variable using VBA in Access. The query returns a value but the variable which it is assigned to has a value of Nothing. Here is the code snippet:

```
Dim queryReturnID As String
queryReturnID = "select dbo_tbl_SupplierReturn.ReturnID from dbo_tbl_SupplierReturn" & _
    " where SupplierID = " & lstPOHdr.Column(1)
Debug.Print queryReturnID
Dim RecordSet1 As DAO.RecordSet
Set RecordSet1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(queryReturnID)
```

Comment: what does `queryReturnID` return?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what's going on with your Nothing recordset; even a query that returns no records would not have the object set to nothing.  As an alternative, however, you could do the same thing with this one line of code:

```
DLookup("ReturnID", "dbo_tbl_SupplierReturn", "SupplierID = " & lstPOHdr.Column(1))
```

Comment: there are a lot of reasons to not use the various domain functions. The OP's table name suggests it is a linked table and dlookups can be very inefficient

Comment: True, fair enough.  I also assumned it would return one value, which it very well may not.